# Pass argument with multiple return points

Tags: kotlin

Assuming I have a function `example()` that has a parameter `param: Int?`. I would like to call it so that the argument can be passed with certain conditionals.

To try to explain better, let's define the `example()` function:

```kotlin
fun example(prev: Int, param: Int?) = doSomething(prev, param)
```

So assuming that under certain conditions, the value passed as an argument can be `null` or any other value. Naturally, I would do something like this:

```kotlin
val param = if (x() > 100) null
            else if (x() < 0) 123
            else 456

example(123, param)
```

Another way to get this to work would be inline `val` like this:

```kotlin
example(123, if (x() > 100) null
             else if (x() < 0) 123
             else 456)
```

The problem is that I have a larger conditional in my real code and it ends up being very "visually accumulated". Both examples works, but I wanted to not using `else` or `when` under these conditions. It would be something like:

```kotlin
example(123, run {
    if (x() > 100)
        return null

    if (x() < 0)
        return 123

    return 456
})
```

However, the code above does not work as expected. The `return` points actually cause the entire flow of the function to return, and are not meant to return as the argument itself.

What I expect, in reality, would be something like the function below:

```kotlin
fun generateExampleArgument(): Int? {
    if (x() > 100)
        return null

    if (x() < 0)
        return 123

    return 456
}

// Then:
example(123, generateExampleArgument())
```

Comment: Didn't understand the need to just inline the function that returns an integer. you can extract a variable, extract function to simplify. Else, instead of taking `Int` param, you can take a lambda `()->Int`

Answer (score 1):

In regard of readability and quote "... larger conditionals ..." the *when* clause is better than the *if ... else if ...* one:

```
example(
  123,
  when {
    x() > 100 -> null
    x() < 0   -> 123
    else      -> 456
  }
)
```

Another possibility is to use a function to pre-calculate the result for the second argument of *example()* or a lambda function, which moves the execution of that function into *example()* itself:

```
fun example(prev: Int, fn: (Int) -> Int?, x: Int) = doSomething(prev, fn(x))

val myLambda = { x: Int ->
 when {
   x > 100 -> null
   x < 0   -> 123
   else    -> 456
 }
}

example(120, myLambda, 111)
```

Comment: Thanks! I use `when()` in situations like the one you described (and actually for the example I gave it actually makes a lot more sense... maybe I made an example too simple for what I intended here). However, I have some slightly larger conditions and nested `if()`'s that might return `null` in some cases.

Comment: Another possibility would be with nested function. Have one _when_ clause for the first level, and call nested functions for nested _ifs_ and _whens_. Thereby the main _when_ remains clean.

Answer (score 0):

After many attempts, I finally figured out how to solve it. My problem is that when using just `return` it actually instructs the return to the "larger function context", not on the argument itself, as expected.

The solution is to use `run` with `return@run`:

```kotlin
example(123, run {
    if (x() > 100)
        return@run null

    if (x() < 0)
        return@run 123

    456
})
```

Comment: Despite that, I was wondering if it would be possible to use nested `run { ... }` and force to `return` in a specific `run` block, some like "named run" (but that's a problem for another day). :)

Comment: fyi, that would be easy to do by labeling the run by writing `run myName@ {` after which you can do `return@myName`

Comment: @IvoBeckers oh! That's amazing! Thanks! Before it I have tried something ike `run myName` only and it not works because of the missing `@`. :) Just to keep a future ref, now I found it on Kotlin doc https://kotlinlang.org/docs/returns.html#return-to-labels.